# How to add custom places in Google Places?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-places-api

I have an android app that displays markers on map when we select from a list of type of places from Google Places. But I want to add my own data onto the map,other than the places in Google Places, given known lang and long. I don't want to use javascript. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can display your own data in a couple of different ways natively on Android.  You can put down a marker at the point of interest with a custom info window.  Here's a [tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/01/create-custom-info-contents-for-by.html).  You could also use an overlay, like a [ground overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/groundoverlay), to show your info directly on the map.  This method can either use pre-made images, or you can create your own bitmaps at runtime.